# Minitest doesn't respect setting config.active_record.pluralize_table_names to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, activerecord, minitest

I've been trying to set up my first tests on Rails 4.2.4 but usually I use singularized table names in DBs, thus I add this line into *config/application.rb*

```
config.active_record.pluralize_table_names = false
```

Since I've being working on Car and User models, let's assume I've already generated each scaffold, and already executed *rake db:test:prepare* so the problem begins with tests as follows:

In test/models/car_test.rb or user_test.rb, first I uncomment stub test "the truth" and run vanilla with the following error with *rake test:models*

```
# Running:

EE

Finished in 0.019095s, 104.7396 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
UserTest#test_the_truth:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DELETE FROM "users"



  2) Error:
CarTest#test_necessary_car_data:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: DELETE FROM "users"


2 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

When I run *rake test:controllers* the same ActiveRecord error shows up multiple times and I cannot fix this behaviour in any way so far.

Somebody else has come across with this issue? It's driving me mad...

PS: All development does well without any issues with singular table names, the only mess lies in testing.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a lot I discovered that Minitest uses each fixture filename to translate into the name of the table in DB. So, when I generated the scaffold, it created *test/fixtures/users.yml*

So I simply changed the filename to user.yml and the test started to work again (I needed to change all fixture filenames).

At the end, it worked but it feels awkward to change manually those names when the generator should be doing that... Does anybody knows where to go to point out this issue with the generator? Would registering a Github issue in official repo be ok?